# Using ssmtp via GMAIL / Intl character set

Tags: email, vim

To send mails to my mailing list, I use ssmtp and gmail send mail.
Mails are sent, received. Good news!
I need to use a french character set, for example : 
-**Jusqu'à présent**
To create the mail's body I use vim, gedit or libreoffice. The locally constructed file looks good. Upon reception it looks like: 
-**Jusqu'Ã  prÃ©sent**
It makes it quite unreadable. I could go via HTML but I prefer to send text files.
Networks are World Wide. Travel Bans are not a solution.
Any workaround?
(An oldtimer who spoke binaryntn

Comment: This sounds like something in your process is not properly encoding the text to UTF-8.

Comment: This issue is not present (on my testing) with msmtp which, unlike ssmtp, is being actively developed. Giv it a try perhaps?